# Add selected in option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have one of the values in my list selected. I also have a hidden field which I have to match the values in the option of the selection. If it finds one then this has to be selected.

This is the code I have.Hidden field html code.

```
   <input type="hidden" id="supp" name="supp" value="<?php echo $_POST['suppliers'];?>" />
```

My js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var addSelected = $('#supp').val();
$("#suppliers option[value='" + addSelected + "']").attr("selected","selected");

console.log(addSelected);
});

</script>
```

The code above is not working.

Comment: put your code in document ready

Comment: Are you getting some error on the javascript console? What is the value of `addSelected`?

Comment: I am a getting the console value which is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jsFiddle that shows a better way to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/ATJvv/

You can just call `.val` on the `<select>` itself.

Comment: It is working. Change the value of the `#supp` hidden input and click run. The select will have that option chosen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#suppliers option").each(function(index, element){
     element.selected = element.value === addSelected;
});
```